# Click event on button that is draggable?

Tags: c#, winforms

So, I made a button that is draggable with these events:

```
bool isMouseClicked;
    private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            isMouseClicked = true;
        }
    }

    private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (isMouseClicked == true)
            //You then set your location of your control. See below:
            button1.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
    }

    private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        isMouseClicked = false;
    }
```

Now, I want to insert something to the "Click" event. When I try to drag the button, the action from the "Click" event is performed. I only want the button to move when I drag it and to perform the action from the "Click" event when I click it. How can I do this?

Comment: *Click* should include check what coordinates still the same for both button down and button up event. Otherwise it's a *drag*. Add small tolerance for *shaking* users.

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest your `bool` should be named `isMouseDown`. Now, the Click event fires when a MouseDown and then MouseUp event occurs on the same control. So add another `bool` `justDragged`, set it to false on MouseDown, set it to true on MouseMove and `isMouseDown` and test it in the Click event.

BTW, this information is on SO, just a bit scattered around.

```
bool isMouseDown = false;
bool justDragged = false;

private void button1_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left) {
        isMouseDown = true;
        justDragged = false;
    }
}

private void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (isMouseDown) {
        //You then set your location of your control. See below:
        button1.Location = new Point(MousePosition.X, MousePosition.Y);
        justDragged = true;
    }
}

private void button1_MouseUp(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    isMouseDown = false;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, MouseEventArgs e) {
    if (!justDragged) { // then we clicked
        // do click handling
    }
}
```

Comment: "set it to true on MouseMove and isMouseDown" what do you mean when you want to say "and isMouseDown"?

Comment: I added the code to make it clearer. What I meant was that `isMouseDown` is true inside the `MouseMove` event then set `justDragged` to true. BTW, don't test a boolean against `true` or `false` :)